# Monty Hall Problem - Could this approach be extended to solution?

Tags: probability, bayesian

I already know the well know and correct solution. However want to explore with my intuition and find the flaw in that.

**Please help me proceed further with my approach (if at all it leads) to solution or let me know the flaw.**

Hypothesis : The car is behind un-chosen door

$U1$ - User chooses gate with car

$U2$ - User chooses gate with goat

$P(U1) = 1/3$

$P(U2) = 2/3$

$P(U1|H) = 0$

$P(H) = 1/3$

$P(U2|H) = 1$    --> Probability of $U2$ when H is known to happen is 1; since gate with car was not selected by user earlier, the goat is only possible choice.

$P(H|U1) = 0$

$P(H|U2) = ((1/3).1) / (2/3) = 1/2$

**Is it possible to take this further to correct solution.**

Comment: What do you mean by correct solution? You probably need to justify how you computed $P(H|U_2)$ but that's it.

Comment: I am not sure if I have edited my question properly to satisfy the need.. Please let me know if I have made it sufficiently clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathsf P(H)=2/3$, not $1/3$

Substituting $C\gets U1$ and $G\gets U2$ to be a little more self-commenting.

> $H$ : Hypothesis the car is behind the unchosen door (ie: switching will win).
>
> $C$ : User chooses gate with car
>
> $G$ : User chooses gate with goat

$${\begin{array}{|l|l|}\hline \mathsf P(C)=1/3 & \mathsf P(H\mid C)=0 & \mathsf P(C\mid H)=0 & \mathsf P(C\cap H)=0\\[1ex] \hline \mathsf P(G) = 2/3 & \mathsf P(H\mid G)=1 & \mathsf P(G\mid H)=1 & \mathsf P(G\cap H)=2/3 \\[1ex] \hline\end{array}\\[2ex] \mathsf P(H) ~{= \mathsf P(G\cap H)+\mathsf P(C\cap H) \\[1ex] = 2/3} }$$

When the user chooses the gate hiding the car, then switching will certainly be a loss.   When the user chooses a gate hiding a goat, then switching will certainly be a win.   The user has a probability of two thirds for choosing a gate hiding a goat.   Therefore the probability that switching will win is $2/3$.

*Remember:* Monty "cheats" and always reveals one of the goats.

Comment: That's not completely true. Initially guest had 1/3 of chance. And 2/3 of chance of loosing, because the other two gates sum up the chances of hiding car behind them. Of the remaining two gates, when one gate with a goat was opened, the only unchosen gate gets whole 2/3 probability of hiding car behind it.

Comment: @stretch  Monty tells you nothing about what the initial choice hides; *however* what revealing one goat's door **does** assure you is that *if you switch* to the remaining door you *will* get the complement of whatever your first choice hides.  So if a goat was behind the first choice, switching *will* obtain the car; and there is a probability of $2/3$ for initially picking a door hiding a goat.